# Can You Link to Google Assistant Action from a Web App

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Can you link to Google Assistant to open it up or even better open up a Google Action from a web app? I know you can link to a Google Action page but you can't seem to link right to the action actually in the assistant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can setup a [link directly to an Action](https://developers.google.com/actions/console/publishing#link_to_your_actions). In the Action Console, you can generate a link and then use this link on a web page. To create the link

From the Action Console, select "Actions" on the left menu and then the right arrow for the Action you want to make a link for

[image]

In the "Links" section header, select the down arrow to expand it

[image]

Once expanded, turn "Would you like to enable a URL for this Action" on and provide a brief description of what your action does when this URL is followed (for example, "start" or "purchase tickets"). You'll then see the URL in an HTML snipped underneath. Make sure to click the "Save" button to save this.

[image]

Comment: You star. Didn't see that before. Thank you very much. This will give me the workaround I need.

Comment: Tried open the generated URL in my mobile. Says "Sorry, I couldn't find that". Am I missing anything.

Comment: I don't know - it has worked for me. Open a new question to show how you're trying to open the URL from mobile.