# How to open Google Assistant App using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api, assistant

I have a webpage with a button called "Open Google Assistant". I want to open 'Google Assistant APP' using JavaScript code.

Please let me know is there any way like - whatsapp://send?text=message to interact / open the Google Assistant APP?

I just want to open "Google Assistant APP" on mobile by pressing a button.
This button will be available in a HTML page, and this html page will be hosted on my website.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can You Link to Google Assistant Action from a Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159850/can-you-link-to-google-assistant-action-from-a-web-app)

Comment: My question is different than the suggested duplicate one.